# xml to html conversion using xslt is not working

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

Here my Xml

```
<document>
  <metadata>
     <title>Sign in to my account</title>
  </metadata>
  <topic>
     <conceptuldocument>
         <legacybold> Hi hello world </legacybold>
      </conceptuldocument>
  </topic>
</document>
```

I only need the title which is under the metadata data tag

all I would need is `<h1> sign in to my account</h1>`

but i am getting out put html as

```
<h1>sign in to my account</h1>Hi hello world
```

here my xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when  test="metadata">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="metadata"/>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="metadata">
    <h1>
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </h1>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

C# :

```
 using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
               
                transform.Transform(xmldocument.DocumentElement,null, sw);
                string html = sw.ToString();
            }
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4XZx.jpg)

[xml image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT9MM.png)

[Xslt file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSMyd.png)

wondering if any one can help me point what am i missing here , very new to xslt its just been a day.

Comment: Well, the main problem with the stylesheet you have posted here is that `metadata` is not a child of the `/` root node. However,  the stylesheet you have posted here does NOT produce the result you claim - so we are obviously not talking about the same thing.

Comment: P.S. Why is your question tagged `xslt-2.0` when you're obviously using XSLT 1.0?

Comment: update to xslt1.0

Comment: well <metadata> is under the <document> (which is the root) why would metadata not be the child.

Comment: Because `metadata` is a child of `document` - which is the root **element**. Your template matches `/` - which is the root **node** (parent of the `document` element). From this context, your test in `<xsl:when  test="metadata">` will return false, and the result will be empty. If you're getting a different result, then you are using a different input and/or a different stylesheet.

Comment: there is no parent for the document .  xml starts from the document tag itself and metadata comes under the document . In this case when i do match / - root node is document.

Comment: I am afraid you are very much mistaken about that - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#data-model

Comment: Ok so here how it is structured when i debug all i can see is  
Document (Container/root node)=> document element(Child of root node)=> metadata(child of document element)

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been trying to tell you. Do note that the **root node** is sometimes called the **document node** - which may be confusing in your case, because the **root element** is named `document`. In any case, we're not making progress on your issue. The situation is still that the result you claim is NOT the result produced by the code you have posted here.

Comment: I have updated the post with images of what i am seeing the output and my xml file

Comment: Here you can see that your XML/XSLT combo produces an empty result: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pP7K7gF. Here you can see that the fix suggested by Michael Kay produces the expected output: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pP7K7gF/1. Perhaps the problem is with your C# code, I wouldn't know about that (my guess is that you're pointing at the wrong file/s).

Comment: from C# instead of sending whole document i am sending DocumentElement
 transform.Transform(xmldocument.DocumentElement,null, sw);  if i send the xmldocument itself fix Michael Kay proposed is working but if i send the DocumentElement to Transform it isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help you with that. The result you get suggests that your 1st template does not match anything in the input. Therefore `metadata` is processed by your 2nd template, and everything else by the built-in template rules that copy text nodes to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest fix is to change your entry template to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document/metadata"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that your `xsl:choose` around the `xsl:apply-templates` is a waste of space. If the element doesn't exist, `xsl:apply-templates` will do nothing.

Comment: Nope it didn't work either , it still gave me  <h1>sign in to my account</h1>Hi hello world

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, but we can't see what unless you supply more information.

Comment: I have updated the post with the image links of my xml , out put , xslt

Comment: That's not very helpful. I can't copy/paste from an image, and I can't (easily) view several images simultaneously. Please post as text.